# Why can't I comment this while loop code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got curious why I can't comment this `while` loop.

I get error

```
 '''while True:
    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 191-192: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape:
```

```
'''while True:
    stop_threads = False
    startTime = datetime.now()
    print("Запуск " + str(countStarts))
    sub = Popen(
        r'C:\Users\RT\Desktop\123.air\контроль cmd\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0' + "\\" + numEmulator + '.bat',
        stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
'''
```

Comment: That's a SyntaxError - it can't come from that line since it doesn't have 192 characters. Please show more of your actual code.

Comment: @AKX those quotes were not meant to format the code in question but actually represent a docstring in code

Comment: @Matiiss True. Rolled back. The point still stands :)

Comment: @AKX not really, the docstring does have more than 192 characters

Comment: Right, I see what's happening now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using triple-quoted strings to "comment out" code. (What you're actually doing is just adding a no-op string literal to your code.)

The `\U` in

```
\Users\RT\Des
```

is being interpreted to start an Unicode escape sequence, but the rest of it is gibberish in Python's eyes.

You have a couple of options:

- use `#` to comment out code, like people do in Python (you can teach your IDE to do that for every line, no need to do it by hand)
- add a `r` marker to the triple-quoted string to avoid those escapes, i.e. `r'''`...

Answer (score 3):

You have a `\U` sequence in your multiline string (not really the same as a comment, although `'''` is sometimes used as a workaround for multiline comments), but the characters that follow it aren't a valid Unicode escape sequence.

An easy fix is to make it a raw string -- add a `r` before the `'''` and the error goes away.

Answer (score 2):

You can not comment this by turning it into a string because you encode unicode characters there, see [the Python documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). The critical characters are `C:\Users`. If you drop there the `U` it will work.
However you can apart from turning your while loop into a string always comment it by turning the section into real comment lines with `#`, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments.